# UseState returns an array for each Game

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am currently making a game discovery website which looks very similar to rawg.io,

I am getting some games from the rawg API provided by rawg.io website and mapping each game to a chakra card component, in that component there is a favorite button so that the user can favorite a game and if the game is favorited it gets stored in an array to be displayed when the user wants to see the favorite games only.

```
 interface Game {
   id: number;
   name: string;
 }

  const [favoriteGames, setFavoriteGames] = useState<Game[]>([]);

  let game = {id: 1, name: 'Portal 2'} /* Here I get the game of the card that is favorited but this is just an example to represent the game card that should be in the array */

  const handleFavourite = (isFavorite: boolean) => {
    if (isFavorite) {
      setFavoriteGames([...favoriteGames, game]);
      console.log(favoriteGames); 
    }
  };
```

Here the isFavourite is a Boolean which determines if the game is favorited or not, if it is favorited we add the favorited game to the array, else the array stays as it is...

When I try to console.log the favoriteGames array the game Portal 2 is added to it but when I try to add another game like for example GTA V I get in the console an array with the game GTA V only...

I kept experimenting for a while and I think the problem that there is a state variable for each game I don't know if this is correct but nothing seems to fix it

Here is an Image of the website if this helps

[image]

Note: Please consider that I'm very new to react and this is the first time for me to make an improvement to the website without any instructions...

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: You could try `setFavoriteGames((favoriteGames) => [...favoriteGames, game]);`

Comment: @T00rk no unfortunately it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The set function only updates the state variable for the next render, so console.log is printing the current state rather than the updated state. [React docs, useState() set functions](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate)

```js
 interface Game {
   id: number;
   name: string;
 }

  const [favoriteGames, setFavoriteGames] = useState<Game[]>([]);

  let game = {id: 1, name: 'Portal 2'}

  // Print favoriteGames whenever it updates
  useEffect(() => console.log(favoriteGames), [favoriteGames]);

  const handleFavourite = (isFavorite: boolean) => {
    if (isFavorite) {
      setFavoriteGames([...favoriteGames, game]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Yeah I know it does that but in the second log the updated value is logged yet the same problem occurs where the state stores one game and forgets about the other games